# Knowing if map has specific custom control in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I created my own custom control for openlayers 3 as follows:

```
window.app = window.app || {};
var app = window.app;

/**
 * Control Creado para moverse por el mapa (quitar controles de dibujar...)
 */
app.Move = function(opt_options) {

  var options = opt_options || {};

  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-hand-o-up"></i>';

  var this_ = this;

  function move_ (){
      console.log();
      map.getControls().forEach(function (control) {
          console.log(control, 'control', window.app.GetFeatureInfo(), 'gfi');
          if(control instanceof (window.app.GetFeatureInfo())) {
              control.activar(false);
          }
          else if(control instanceof (new app.Draw())){
              control.removeDraw();
              control.removeModify();
              control.activar(false);
          }
      });
  }

  button.addEventListener('click', move_, false);

  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'left');
  element.setAttribute('title', 'Mover');
  element.setAttribute('data-content', 'Desplazarse por el mapa');
  element.className = 'move ol-unselectable ol-control';
  element.appendChild(button);

  ol.control.Control.call(this, {
    element: element,
    target: options.target
  });

};
ol.inherits(app.Move, ol.control.Control);
map.addControl(new app.Move());
```

In this control I want to 'turn off' other custom constrols.
What I have done is to get all controls in the map and look up for my specific control using `instanceof` method.

```
  map.getControls().forEach(function (control) {
      //console.log(control, 'control', window.app.GetFeatureInfo(), 'gfi');
      if(control instanceof (window.app.GetFeatureInfo())) {
          control.activar(false);
      }
      else if(control instanceof (new app.Draw())){
          control.removeDraw();
          control.removeModify();
          control.activar(false);
      }
  });
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: invalid 'instanceof' operand window.app.GetFeatureInfo(...)
```

How can I get a valid instance of custom control to compare it with the same custom control setted in the map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.app.GetFeatureInfo()` and `new app.Draw()` are calls for new constructors and not the constructors themselfes. 
Instead you should use `control instanceof app.Move` or `control instanceof app.GetFeatureInfo`. Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/n89vkew5/1/) of you code. I am just logging the controls. Here is also some [info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) about the `instanceof`. Check the examples

`var myString  = new String();
myString  instanceof String; // returns true`

Answer (score 2):

I finally found myself what's going on.

`instanceof` method espected a constructor and the right code would be:

```
control instanceof (new window.app.GetFeatureInfo()).constructor)
```